# NPM install go nuts in this VSCode project please advice

Tags: reactjs, npm, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors

I Learn React and testing [this](https://github.com/pgast/orders) repo. When I clone and do NPM install I get this long output:

(Note: Stackoverflow alow max 30.000 letters, original output was 300.000 )

```
            Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1082]
            (c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. Med ensamrätt.
            
            L:\react\PropertyFinder>cd L:\temp\orders-master\orders-master
            
            L:\temp\orders-master\orders-master>npm install
            npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.4: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
            npm WARN deprecated core-js@1.2.7: core-js@<2.6.8 is no longer maintained. Please, upgrade to core-js@3 or at least to actual version of core-js@2.
to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
            npm WARN deprecated circular-json@0.3.3: CircularJSON is in maintenance only, flatted is its successor.
            npm WARN deprecated hoek@4.2.1: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
            npm WARN deprecated topo@2.0.2: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
            npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
            npm WARN deprecated request-promise-native@1.0.9: request-promise-native has been deprecated because it extends the now deprecated request package, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
            npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
            
            > grpc@1.20.0 install L:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc
            > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library
            
            node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
            node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.20.0/node-v72-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz
            node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for grpc@1.20.0 and node@12.8.1 (node-v72 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
            Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
              win_delay_load_hook.cc
              WINDOWS_BUILD_WARNING.vcxproj -> L:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\build\Release\\WINDOWS_BUILD_WARNING.node
              err_data.c
              a_bitstr.c
              a_bool.c
              a_d2i_fp.c
              a_dup.c
              a_enum.c
              a_gentm.c
            l:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\include\openssl\base.h(143): warning C4005: 'OPENSSL_THREA
            DS': macro redefinition (compiling source file ..\deps\grpc\src\boringssl\err_data.c) [L:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\bui
            ld\boringssl.vcxproj]
              l:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\src\boringssl\err_data.c: note: see previous definition of 'OPENSSL_THREADS'
            l:\temp\orders-master\orders-
            c:\users\user\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.8.1\include\node\openssl\ossl_typ.h(91): error C2371: 'EVP_MD': redefinition; different basic type
            s (compiling source file ..\deps\grpc\src\boringssl\err_data.c) [L:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\build\boringssl.vcxproj]
              l:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\include\openssl\base.h(304): note: see declaration of 'E
              VP_MD' (compiling source file ..\deps\grpc\src\boringssl\err_data.c)
            c:\users\user\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.8.1\include\node\openssl\ossl_typ.h(92): error C2371: 'EVP_MD_CTX': redefinition; different basic
            types (compiling source file ..\deps\grpc\src\boringssl\err_data.c) [L:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\build\boringssl.vcxpr
            oj]
              l:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\include\openssl\base.h(303): note: see declaration of 'E
              VP_MD_CTX' (compiling source file ..\deps\grpc\src\boringssl\err_data.c)
            c:\users\user\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.8.1\include\node\openssl\ossl_typ.h(100): error C2371: 'EVP_ENCODE_CTX': redefinition; different b
            asic types (compiling source file ..\deps\grpc\src\boringssl\err_data.c) [L:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\build\boringssl.
            vcxproj]
              l:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\include\openssl\base.h(308): note: see declaration of 'E
              VP_ENCODE_CTX' (compiling source file ..\deps\grpc\src\boringssl\err_data.c)
            c:\users\user\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.8.1\include\node\openssl\crypto.h(231): error C2371: 'CRYPTO_THREADID': redefinition; different ba
            sic types (compiling source file ..\deps\grpc\src\boringssl\err_data.c)l:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\third_par
            ty\boringssl\include\openssl\base.h(143): warning C4005: 'OPENSSL_THREADS': macro redefinition (compiling source file ..\deps\grpc\third_party\b
            oringssl\crypto\asn1\a_d2i_fp.c) [L:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\build\boringssl.vcxproj]
            
              l:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\include\openssl\base.h(231): note: see declaration of 'C
              RYPTO_THREADID' (compiling source file ..\deps\grpc\src\boringssl\err_data.c)l:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\t
              hird_party\boringssl\crypto\asn1\a_d2i_fp.c: note: see previous definition of 'OPENSSL_THREADS'
            
            l:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\include\openssl\base.h(147): warning C4005: 'OPENSSL_VERSI
            ON_NUMBER': macro redefinition (compiling source file ..\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\crypto\asn1\a_d2i_fp.c) [L:\temp\orders-master\orders-m
            aster\node_modules\grpc\build\boringssl.vcxproj]
              c:\users\user\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.8.1\include\node\openssl\opensslv.h(42): note: see previous definition of 'OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBE
              R' (compiling source file ..\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\crypto\asn1\a_d2i_fp.c)
            l:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\include\openssl\base.h(143): warning C4005: 'OPENSSL_THREA
            DS': macro redefinition (compiling source file ..\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\crypto\asn1\a_bool.c) [L:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\nod
            e_modules\grpc\build\boringssl.vcxproj]
              l:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\crypto\asn1\a_bool.c: note: see previous definition of '
              OPENSSL_THREADS'
            l:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\include\openssl\base.h(182): warning C4005: 'OPENSSL_EXPOR
            T': macro redefinition (compiling source file ..\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\crypto\asn1\a_d2i_fp.c) [L:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\no
            de_modules\grpc\build\boringssl.vcxproj]
              c:\users\user\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.8.1\include\node\openssl\e_os2.h(171): note: see previous definition of 'OPENSSL_EXPORT' (compil
              ing source file ..\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\crypto\asn1\a_d2i_fp.c)
            l:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\include\openssl\base.h(147): warning C4005: 'OPENSSL_VERSI
            ON_NUMBER': macro redefinition (compiling source file ..\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\crypto\asn1\a_bool.c) [L:\temp\orders-master\orders-mas
            ter\node_modules\grpc\build\boringssl.vcxproj]
              c:\users\user\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.8.1\include\node\openssl\opensslv.h(42): note: see previous definition of 'OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBE
              R' (compiling source file ..\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\crypto\asn1\a_bool.c)
            l:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\include\openssl\base.h(231): error C2371: 'CRYPTO_THREADID
            ': redefinition; different basic types (compiling source file ..\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\crypto\asn1\a_d2i_fp.c)l:\temp\orders-master\or
            ders-master\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\include\openssl\base.h(182): warning C4005: 'OPENSSL_EXPORT': macro redefinition (
            compiling source file ..\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\crypto\asn1\a_bool.c) [L:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\build\bori
            ngssl.vcxproj]
            
              c:\users\user\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.8.1\include\node\openssl\crypto.h(231): note: see declaration of 'CRYPTO_THREADID' (compiling so
              urce file ..\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\crypto\asn1\a_d2i_fp.c)c:\users\user\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.8.1\include\node\openssl\e_o
              s2.h(171): note: see previous definition of 'OPENSSL_EXPORT' (compiling source file ..\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\crypto\asn1\a_bool.c)
            
            l:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\src\boringssl\err_data.c(33): error C2118: negative subscript [L:\temp\orders-ma
            ster\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\build\boringssl.vcxproj]
            l:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\include\openssl\base.h(143): warning C4005: 'OPENSSL_THREA
            DS': macro redefinition (compiling source file ..\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\crypto\asn1\a_bitstr.c) [L:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\n
            ode_modules\grpc\build\boringssl.vcxproj]
              l:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\crypto\asn1\a_bitstr.c: note: see previous definition of
               'OPENSSL_THREADS'
            l:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\include\openssl\base.h(143): warning C4005: 'OPENSSL_THREA
            DS': macro redefinition (compiling source file ..\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\crypto\asn1\a_dup.c) [L:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node
            _modules\grpc\build\boringssl.vcxproj]
              l:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\crypto\asn1\a_dup.c: note: see previous definition of 'O
              PENSSL_THREADS'
            l:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\include\openssl\base.h(303): error C2371: 'EVP_MD_CTX': re
            definition; different basic types (compiling source file ..\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\crypto\asn1\a_d2i_fp.c)l:\temp\orders-master\orders-
            master\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\include\openssl\base.h(231): error C2371: 'CRYPTO_THREADID': redefinition; different ba
            sic types (compiling source file ..\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\crypto\asn1\a_bool.c) [L:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc
            \build\boringssl.vcxproj]
            l:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\src\boringssl\err_data.c(34): error C2118: negative subscript [L:\temp\orders-ma
            ster\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\build\boringssl.vcxproj]
           'OPENSSL_EXPOR
            T': macro redefinition (compiling source file ..\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\crypto\asn1\a_dup.c) [L:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_
            modules\grpc\build\boringssl.vcxproj]
              c:\users\user\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.8.1\include\node\openssl\e_os2.h(171): note: see previous definition of 'OPENSSL_EXPORT' (compil
              ing source file ..\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\crypto\asn1\a_dup.c)
            l:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\src\boringssl\err_data.c(36): error C2118: negative subscript [L:\temp\orders-ma
            ster\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\build\boringssl.vcxproj]
            l:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\include\openssl\base.h(308): error C2371: 'EVP_ENCODE_CTX'
            : redefinition; different basic types (compiling source file ..\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\crypto\asn1\a_d2i_fp.c) [L:\temp\orders-master\o
            rders-master\node_modules\grpc\build\boringssl.vcxproj]
            l:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\include\openssl\base.h(182): warning C4005: 'OPENSSL_EXPOR
            T': macro redefinition (compiling source file ..\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\crypto\asn1\a_enum.c)l:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_m
            odules\grpc\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\include\openssl\base.h(304): error C2371: 'EVP_MD': redefinition; different basic types (compiling s
            ource file ..\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\crypto\asn1\a_bool.c) [L:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\build\boringssl.vcxpr
            oj]
              c:\users\user\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.8.1\include\node\openssl\ossl_typ.h(100): note: see declaration of 'EVP_ENCODE_CTX' (compiling s
              ource file ..\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\crypto\asn1\a_d2i_fp.c)
            
              c:\users\user\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.8.1\include\node\openssl\e_os2.h(171): note: see previous definition of 'OPENSSL_EXPORT' (compil
              ing source file ..\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\crypto\asn1\a_enum.c)c:\users\user\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.8.1\include\node\openssl
              \ossl_typ.h(91): note: see declaration of 'EVP_MD' (compiling source file ..\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\crypto\asn1\a_bool.c)
            
            l:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\include\openssl\base.h(231): error C2371: 'CRYPTO_THREADID
            ': redefinition; different basic types (compiling source file ..\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\crypto\asn1\a_bitstr.c)l:\temp\orders-master\or
            ders-master\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\include\openssl\base.h(231): error C2371: 'CRYPTO_THREADID': redefinition; differe
            nt basic types (compiling source file ..\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\crypto\asn1\a_dup.c)l:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\gr
            pc\deps\grpc\src\boringssl\err_data.c(37): error C2118: negative subscript [L:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\build\boringss
            l.vcxproj]
            
            
            l:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\include\openssl\base.h(308): error C2371: 'EVP_ENCODE_CTX'
        
              BJECT_FLAG_DYNAMIC': undeclared identifier
            
            l:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\crypto\asn1\a_object.c(241): error C2037: left of 'flags'
            specifies undefined struct/union 'asn1_object_st' [L:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\build\boringssl.vcxproj]
            l:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\crypto\asn1\a_strnid.c(67): error C2084: function 'sk_ASN1
            _STRING_TABLE_compfunc sk_ASN1_STRING_TABLE_set_cmp_func(stack_st_ASN1_STRING_TABLE *,sk_ASN1_STRING_TABLE_compfunc)' already has a bodyl:\temp\
            orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\crypto\asn1\a_object.c(241): error C2065: 'ASN1_OBJECT_FLAG_DYNAMI
            C_STRINGS': undeclared identifier [L:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\build\boringssl.vcxproj]
            
            l:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\crypto\asn1\a_object.c(245): error C2037: left of 'sn' spe
            cifies undefined struct/union 'asn1_object_st'c:\users\user\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.8.1\include\node\openssl\asn1.h(194): note: see prev
            ious definition of 'sk_ASN1_STRING_TABLE_set_cmp_func' [L:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\build\boringssl.vcxproj]
            
        
            cifies undefined struct/union 'asn1_object_st' [L:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\build\boringssl.vcxproj]
            l:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\crypto\asn1\a_strnid.c(226): warning C4133: 'function': in
            compatible types - from 'size_t *' to 'ASN1_STRING_TABLE *' [L:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\build\boringssl.vcxproj]
            l:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\crypto\asn1\a_object.c(250): error C2037: left of 'ln' spe
            cifies undefined struct/union 'asn1_object_st' [L:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\build\boringssl.vcxproj]
            l:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\crypto\asn1\a_strnid.c(226): warning C4020: 'sk_ASN1_STRIN
            G_TABLE_find': too many actual parameters [L:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\build\boringssl.vcxproj]
            l:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\crypto\asn1\a_object.c(252): error C2037: left of 'flags'
            specifies undefined struct/union 'asn1_object_st' [L:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\build\boringssl.vcxproj]
            l:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\crypto\asn1\a_object.c(252): error C2065: 'ASN1_OBJECT_FLA
            G_DYNAMIC_DATA': undeclared identifier [L:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\build\boringssl.vcxproj]
            l:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\crypto\asn1\a_object.c(253): error C2037: left of 'data' s
            pecifies undefined struct/union 'asn1_object_st' [L:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\build\boringssl.vcxproj]
            l:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\crypto\asn1\a_object.c(254): error C2037: left of 'data' s
            pecifies undefined struct/union 'asn1_object_st' [L:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\build\boringssl.vcxproj]
            l:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\crypto\asn1\a_strnid.c(240): warning C4028: formal paramet
            er 1 different from declaration [L:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\build\boringssl.vcxproj]
            l:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\crypto\asn1\a_object.c(255): error C2037: left of 'data' s
            pecifies undefined struct/union 'asn1_object_st' [L:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\build\boringssl.vcxproj]
            l:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\crypto\asn1\a_strnid.c(240): warning C4028: formal paramet
            er 2 different from declaration [L:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\build\boringssl.vcxproj]
            l:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\crypto\asn1\a_object.c(256): error C2037: left of 'length'
             specifies undefined struct/union 'asn1_object_st' [L:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\build\boringssl.vcxproj]
            l:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\crypto\asn1\a_strnid.c(242): warning C4013: 'OPENSSL_PUT_E
            RROR' undefined; assuming extern returning int [L:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\build\boringssl.vcxproj]
            l:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\crypto\asn1\a_object.c(258): error C2037: left of 'flags'
            specifies undefined struct/union 'asn1_object_st' [L:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\build\boringssl.vcxproj]
            l:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\crypto\asn1\a_strnid.c(242): error C2065: 'ASN1': undeclar
            ed identifier [L:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\build\boringssl.vcxproj]
            l:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\crypto\asn1\a_object.c(258): error C2065: 'ASN1_OBJECT_FLA
            G_DYNAMIC': undeclared identifier [L:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\build\boringssl.vcxproj]
            l:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\crypto\asn1\a_strnid.c(246): warning C4013: 'OPENSSL_mallo
            c' undefined; assuming extern returning int [L:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\build\boringssl.vcxproj]
            l:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\crypto\asn1\a_object.c(265): error C2079: 'o' uses undefin
            ed struct 'asn1_object_st' [L:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\build\boringssl.vcxproj]
            l:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\crypto\asn1\a_strnid.c(246): warning C4047: '=': 'ASN1_STR
            ING_TABLE *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int' [L:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\build\boringssl.vcxproj]
            l:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\crypto\asn1\a_object.c(267): error C2224: left of '.sn' mu
            st have struct/union type [L:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\build\boringssl.vcxproj]
            l:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\crypto\asn1\a_strnid.c(248): error C2065: 'ASN1': undeclar
            ed identifier [L:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\build\boringssl.vcxproj]
            l:\temp\orders-master\orders-                must have struct/union type [L:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\build\boringssl.vcxproj]
            l:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\crypto\asn1\a_object.c(270): error C2224: left of '.nid' m
            ust have struct/union type [L:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\build\boringssl.vcxproj]
            l:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\crypto\asn1\a_object.c(271): error C2224: left of '.length
    master\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\crypto\asn1\a_object.c(273): error C2065: 'ASN1_OBJECT_FLA
            G_DYNAMIC_DATA': undeclared identifier [L:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\build\boringssl.vcxproj]
            l:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\crypto\asn1\a_object.c(274): warning C4133: 'function': in
            compatible types - from 'int *' to 'const ASN1_OBJECT *' [L:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\build\boringssl.vcxproj]
            cl : Command line error D8040: error creating or communicating with child process [L:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\build\b
            oringssl.vcxproj]
              alloc.cc
              arena.cc
              atm.cc
              cpu_iphone.cc
              cpu_linux.cc
              cpu_posix.cc
              cpu_windows.cc
              sync_windows.cc
              time.cc
              time_posix.cc
              time_precise.cc
              time_windows.cc
              tls_pthread.cc
              tmpfile_msys.cc
              tmpfile_posix.cc
              tmpfile_windows.cc
              wrap_memcpy.cc
              fork.cc
              thd_posix.cc
              thd_windows.cc
              basic_timers.cc
              stap_timers.cc
              win_delay_load_hook.cc
              gpr.vcxproj -> L:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\node_modules\grpc\build\Release\\libgpr.lib
              init.cc
              avl.cc
              backoff.cc
              channel_args.cc
              channel_stack.cc
              channel_stack_builder.cc
              channel_trace.cc
              channelz.cc
              channelz_registry.cc
              connected_channel.cc
              stream_compression_identity.cc
              stats.cc
              stats_data.cc
              format_request.cc
              httpcli.cc
              parser.cc
              buffer_list.cc
              call_combiner.cc
              combiner.cc
              endpoint.cc
              endpoint_pair_posix.cc
              endpoint_pair_uv.cc
              endpoint_pair_windows.cc
          
            npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
            npm ERR! errno 1
            npm ERR! grpc@1.20.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
            npm ERR! Exit status 1
            npm ERR!
            npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.20.0 install script.
            npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
            
            npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
            npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-10-10T20_19_23_986Z-debug.log
            
            L:\temp\orders-master\orders-master>
```

Most of the output is color red:

[image]

I try to delete NODE_MODULES folder and package-lock.json file but no changes. I can start the NPM start but with compilation error:

```
./src/components/Firebase/firebase.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'firebase/app' in 'L:\temp\orders-master\orders-master\src\components\Firebase'
```

So I try to install it `npm i firebase@^5.11.1` and that gave me the same long Terminal output.
Earlier today I tried 3 GitHub Reacatjs project and some CodeSandbox project and my VSCode and the projects compile and run as they should.
Any ide?

Is there something in the package.json tha can cause this:

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "react-firebase-authentication",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^5.11.1",
    "print-js": "^1.3.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.1",
    "recompose": "^0.30.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom --passWithNoTests",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

I create a new create-react-app project and copy over src file and get the same massive error output.
Any idea what I can do?

I created a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-volhard-hk6lq?file=/package.json) and Codesandbox itself get confused:

> Error The error you provided does not contain a stack trace.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think so there may be an error in the repo or the path settings of your and repo holders may be different.

I advise you to first try to clone and run some small react projects. It that works then it must be repo problems which you will need to fix in the code/way of paths

If that also doesn't work, try checking your environment vars!

Comment: I can create-react-app and run it in VSCode so my NPM source looks ok. I also run this now in [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-volhard-hk6lq?file=/.env) and Codesandbox itself get confused:

Comment: I also run this now in [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-volhard-hk6lq?file=/.env) and Codesandbox itself get confused:

Comment: ok I got a lead, I just added "firebase": "^5.11.1" that is in the faulty projects package.json to the package.json of a new create-react-app. That gave me the same mega error

Comment: Yea that's it just needed the latest "firebase": "^7.23.0"

Comment: Rather than writing the version of the module, just write the name, npm will automatically download the latest version.

Comment: And if you want a particular version than make sure about the spelling/numbers.\

Answer (score 0):

hehe
just needed the latest "firebase": "^7.23.0".

I think this is an NPM bug because it's not user friendly att all.

Created a [BUG Strange non user friendly behavior controlled by the package itself #1944](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/1944) issues